# chosen direction rtl horizontal scroll issue

Tags: html, css, jquery-chosen

When the page direction is set to 'rtl; it creates horizontal scroll. I've used chosen plugin. it creates unwanted "left: -9999px;" for "chosen-drop" div class. please help me to solve this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I've added "direction:rtl;" into body and html tags. then it creates horizontal scroll

Comment: @Tushar i've added screenshots

Comment: @dHaRa uMarAniYa i've added screenshots

Comment: You were asked to post code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 9999px;
    z-index: 1010;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 0;
    background: #d1d0d0;
}
```

Find and Change this with your "chosen.css" file. However "left: -9999px;" should be changed into "left: 9999px;"

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that when your page is RTL, you also configure your chosen selects be RTL. As mentioned in https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ Try

```
<select class="chosen-select chosen-rtl">
```

If all your selects are rtl you can can add `chosen-rtl` to them all before calling `chosen` do like:

```
$('select:visible').addClass("chosen-rtl");
$('select:visible').chosen();
```

It is much better than tweaking the component css ;)

Comment: I have exactly same issue and this worked for me, you need to configure chosen to work in rtl mode. I have reviewed your code, please add  `chosen-rtl` to your select and test again

Answer (score 0):

Change the     `left:-9000`     to     `display:none`     in `chosen.css` and `jquery.chosen.j`s. This is a known issue with Chosen.
It is working well for me.

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/447

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/3386

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following custom css and it is working for me

```
html{
direction:ltr;
}
```